# "Not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation"

Tags: c++, heap, quicksort, mergesort, insertion-sort

I'm beginning a program using heaps in which I must insertSort, mergeSort, and quickSort into the heap. I was instructed to use the code from my textbook as a basis and I cannot even get the example code to compile. I keep receiving the error:

```
not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation
```

Now I think it has something to do with the order in which the template<> classes were declared in the Sort.h file. However, I can't imagine a textbook would publish code that simply doesn't compile. Would you guys mind taking a look?

Full errors:

```
In file included from Driver.cpp:4:0:
Sort.h: In instantiation of 'void heapsort(std::vector<Comparable>&) [with Comparable = int]':
Driver.cpp:47:21:   required from here
Sort.h:79:9: error: 'percDown' was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
Sort.h:104:6: note: 'template<class Comparable> void percDown(std::vector<Comparable>&, int, int)' declared here, later in the translation unit
Sort.h:83:9: error: 'percDown' was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
Sort.h:104:6: note: 'template<class Comparable> void percDown(std::vector<Comparable>&, int, int)' declared here, later in the translation unit
Sort.h: In instantiation of 'void mergeSort(std::vector<Comparable>&, std::vector<Comparable>&, int, int) [with Comparable = int]':
Sort.h:150:5:   required from 'void mergeSort(std::vector<Comparable>&) [with Comparable = int]'
Driver.cpp:53:22:   required from here
Sort.h:138:9: error: 'merge' was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
Sort.h:163:6: note: 'template<class Comparable> void merge(std::vector<Comparable>&, std::vector<Comparable>&, int, int, int)' declared here, later in the translation unit
```

Sort.h:

```
#ifndef SORT_H
#define SORT_H

/**
 * Several sorting routines.
 * Arrays are rearranged with smallest item first.
 */

#include <vector>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

/**
 * Simple insertion sort.
 */
template <typename Comparable>
void insertionSort( vector<Comparable> & a )
{
    for( int p = 1; p < a.size( ); ++p )
    {
        Comparable tmp = std::move( a[ p ] );

        int j;
        for( j = p; j > 0 && tmp < a[ j - 1 ]; --j )
            a[ j ] = std::move( a[ j - 1 ] );
        a[ j ] = std::move( tmp );
    }
}


/**
 * Internal insertion sort routine for subarrays
 * that is used by quicksort.
 * a is an array of Comparable items.
 * left is the left-most index of the subarray.
 * right is the right-most index of the subarray.
 */
template <typename Comparable>
void insertionSort( vector<Comparable> & a, int left, int right )
{
    for( int p = left + 1; p <= right; ++p )
    {
        Comparable tmp = std::move( a[ p ] );
        int j;

        for( j = p; j > left && tmp < a[ j - 1 ]; --j )
            a[ j ] = std::move( a[ j - 1 ] );
        a[ j ] = std::move( tmp );
    }
}



/**
 * Shellsort, using Shell's (poor) increments.
 */
template <typename Comparable>
void shellsort( vector<Comparable> & a )
{
    for( int gap = a.size( ) / 2; gap > 0; gap /= 2 )
        for( int i = gap; i < a.size( ); ++i )
        {
            Comparable tmp = std::move( a[ i ] );
            int j = i;

            for( ; j >= gap && tmp < a[ j - gap ]; j -= gap )
                a[ j ] = std::move( a[ j - gap ] );
            a[ j ] = std::move( tmp );
        }
}

/**
 * Standard heapsort.
 */
template <typename Comparable>
void heapsort( vector<Comparable> & a )
{
    for( int i = a.size( ) / 2 - 1; i >= 0; --i )  /* buildHeap */
        percDown( a, i, a.size( ) );
    for( int j = a.size( ) - 1; j > 0; --j )
    {
        std::swap( a[ 0 ], a[ j ] );               /* deleteMax */
        percDown( a, 0, j );
    }
}

/**
 * Internal method for heapsort.
 * i is the index of an item in the heap.
 * Returns the index of the left child.
 */
inline int leftChild( int i )
{
    return 2 * i + 1;
}

/**
 * Internal method for heapsort that is used in
 * deleteMax and buildHeap.
 * i is the position from which to percolate down.
 * n is the logical size of the binary heap.
 */
template <typename Comparable>
void percDown( vector<Comparable> & a, int i, int n )
{
    int child;
    Comparable tmp;

    for( tmp = std::move( a[ i ] ); leftChild( i ) < n; i = child )
    {
        child = leftChild( i );
        if( child != n - 1 && a[ child ] < a[ child + 1 ] )
            ++child;
        if( tmp < a[ child ] )
            a[ i ] = std::move( a[ child ] );
        else
            break;
    }
    a[ i ] = std::move( tmp );
}

/**
 * Internal method that makes recursive calls.
 * a is an array of Comparable items.
 * tmpArray is an array to place the merged result.
 * left is the left-most index of the subarray.
 * right is the right-most index of the subarray.
 */
template <typename Comparable>
void mergeSort( vector<Comparable> & a,
                vector<Comparable> & tmpArray, int left, int right )
{
    if( left < right )
    {
        int center = ( left + right ) / 2;
        mergeSort( a, tmpArray, left, center );
        mergeSort( a, tmpArray, center + 1, right );
        merge( a, tmpArray, left, center + 1, right );
    }
}

/**
 * Mergesort algorithm (driver).
 */
template <typename Comparable>
void mergeSort( vector<Comparable> & a )
{
    vector<Comparable> tmpArray( a.size( ) );

    mergeSort( a, tmpArray, 0, a.size( ) - 1 );
}


/**
 * Internal method that merges two sorted halves of a subarray.
 * a is an array of Comparable items.
 * tmpArray is an array to place the merged result.
 * leftPos is the left-most index of the subarray.
 * rightPos is the index of the start of the second half.
 * rightEnd is the right-most index of the subarray.
 */
template <typename Comparable>
void merge( vector<Comparable> & a, vector<Comparable> & tmpArray,
            int leftPos, int rightPos, int rightEnd )
{
    int leftEnd = rightPos - 1;
    int tmpPos = leftPos;
    int numElements = rightEnd - leftPos + 1;

    // Main loop
    while( leftPos <= leftEnd && rightPos <= rightEnd )
        if( a[ leftPos ] <= a[ rightPos ] )
            tmpArray[ tmpPos++ ] = std::move( a[ leftPos++ ] );
        else
            tmpArray[ tmpPos++ ] = std::move( a[ rightPos++ ] );

    while( leftPos <= leftEnd )    // Copy rest of first half
        tmpArray[ tmpPos++ ] = std::move( a[ leftPos++ ] );

    while( rightPos <= rightEnd )  // Copy rest of right half
        tmpArray[ tmpPos++ ] = std::move( a[ rightPos++ ] );

    // Copy tmpArray back
    for( int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i, --rightEnd )
        a[ rightEnd ] = std::move( tmpArray[ rightEnd ] );
}


/**
 * Return median of left, center, and right.
 * Order these and hide the pivot.
 */
template <typename Comparable>
const Comparable & median3( vector<Comparable> & a, int left, int right )
{
    int center = ( left + right ) / 2;

    if( a[ center ] < a[ left ] )
        std::swap( a[ left ], a[ center ] );
    if( a[ right ] < a[ left ] )
        std::swap( a[ left ], a[ right ] );
    if( a[ right ] < a[ center ] )
        std::swap( a[ center ], a[ right ] );

        // Place pivot at position right - 1
    std::swap( a[ center ], a[ right - 1 ] );
    return a[ right - 1 ];
}

/**
 * Internal quicksort method that makes recursive calls.
 * Uses median-of-three partitioning and a cutoff of 10.
 * a is an array of Comparable items.
 * left is the left-most index of the subarray.
 * right is the right-most index of the subarray.
 */
template <typename Comparable>
void quicksort( vector<Comparable> & a, int left, int right )
{
    if( left + 10 <= right )
    {
        const Comparable & pivot = median3( a, left, right );

            // Begin partitioning
        int i = left, j = right - 1;
        for( ; ; )
        {
            while( a[ ++i ] < pivot ) { }
            while( pivot < a[ --j ] ) { }
            if( i < j )
                std::swap( a[ i ], a[ j ] );
            else
                break;
        }

        std::swap( a[ i ], a[ right - 1 ] );  // Restore pivot

        quicksort( a, left, i - 1 );     // Sort small elements
        quicksort( a, i + 1, right );    // Sort large elements
    }
    else  // Do an insertion sort on the subarray
        insertionSort( a, left, right );
}

/**
 * Quicksort algorithm (driver).
 */
template <typename Comparable>
void quicksort( vector<Comparable> & a )
{
    quicksort( a, 0, a.size( ) - 1 );
}


/**
 * Internal selection method that makes recursive calls.
 * Uses median-of-three partitioning and a cutoff of 10.
 * Places the kth smallest item in a[k-1].
 * a is an array of Comparable items.
 * left is the left-most index of the subarray.
 * right is the right-most index of the subarray.
 * k is the desired rank (1 is minimum) in the entire array.
 */
template <typename Comparable>
void quickSelect( vector<Comparable> & a, int left, int right, int k )
{
    if( left + 10 <= right )
    {
        const Comparable & pivot = median3( a, left, right );

            // Begin partitioning
        int i = left, j = right - 1;
        for( ; ; )
        {
            while( a[ ++i ] < pivot ) { }
            while( pivot < a[ --j ] ) { }
            if( i < j )
                std::swap( a[ i ], a[ j ] );
            else
                break;
        }

        std::swap( a[ i ], a[ right - 1 ] );  // Restore pivot

            // Recurse; only this part changes
        if( k <= i )
            quickSelect( a, left, i - 1, k );
        else if( k > i + 1 )
            quickSelect( a, i + 1, right, k );
    }
    else  // Do an insertion sort on the subarray
        insertionSort( a, left, right );
}

/**
 * Quick selection algorithm.
 * Places the kth smallest item in a[k-1].
 * a is an array of Comparable items.
 * k is the desired rank (1 is minimum) in the entire array.
 */
template <typename Comparable>
void quickSelect( vector<Comparable> & a, int k )
{
    quickSelect( a, 0, a.size( ) - 1, k );
}


template <typename Comparable>
void SORT( vector<Comparable> & items )
{
    if( items.size( ) > 1 )
    {
        vector<Comparable> smaller;
        vector<Comparable> same;
        vector<Comparable> larger;

        auto chosenItem = items[ items.size( ) / 2 ];

        for( auto & i : items )
        {
            if( i < chosenItem )
                smaller.push_back( std::move( i ) );
            else if( chosenItem < i )
                larger.push_back( std::move( i ) );
            else
                same.push_back( std::move( i ) );
        }

        SORT( smaller );     // Recursive call!
        SORT( larger );      // Recursive call!

        std::move( begin( smaller ), end( smaller ), begin( items ) );
        std::move( begin( same ), end( same ), begin( items ) + smaller.size( ) );
        std::move( begin( larger ), end( larger ), end( items ) - larger.size( ) );

/*
        items.clear( );
        items.insert( end( items ), begin( smaller ), end( smaller ) );
        items.insert( end( items ), begin( same ), end( same ) );
        items.insert( end( items ), begin( larger ), end( larger ) );
*/
    }
}

/*
 * This is the more public version of insertion sort.
 * It requires a pair of iterators and a comparison
 * function object.
 */
template <typename RandomIterator, typename Comparator>
void insertionSort( const RandomIterator & begin,
                    const RandomIterator & end,
                    Comparator lessThan )
{
    if( begin == end )
        return;

    RandomIterator j;

    for( RandomIterator p = begin+1; p != end; ++p )
    {
        auto tmp = std::move( *p );
        for( j = p; j != begin && lessThan( tmp, *( j-1 ) ); --j )
            *j = std::move( *(j-1) );
        *j = std::move( tmp );
    }
}

/*
 * The two-parameter version calls the three parameter version, using C++11 decltype
 */
template <typename RandomIterator>
void insertionSort( const RandomIterator & begin,
                    const RandomIterator & end )
{
    insertionSort( begin, end, less<decltype(*begin )>{ } );
}



#endif
```

And Driver.cpp

//Driver.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sort.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <time.h> 

using namespace std;

void checkSort( const vector<int> & a )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < a.size( ); ++i )
        if(a.size( ) != i )
            cout << "Error at " << i << endl;
    cout << "Finished checksort" << endl;
}

int main( )
{
    srand(time(NULL)); 

    int vec_length;

    cout << "What would you like the length of the vector to be?" << endl;
    cin >> vec_length;

    vector<int> a(vec_length);

    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    {
        a[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
    }

    //vector<string> a( NUM_ITEMS );        // This input adds factor of N to running time
    //for( int i = 1; i < a.size( ); ++i )  // but we want to test std::move logic
      //  a[ i ] = a[ i - 1 ] + 'a';

    for( int theSeed = 0; theSeed < 10; ++theSeed )
    {
        insertionSort( a );
        checkSort( a );

        insertionSort( begin( a ), end( a ) );
        checkSort( a );

        heapsort( a );
        checkSort( a );

        shellsort( a );
        checkSort( a );

        mergeSort( a );
        checkSort( a );

        quicksort( a );
        checkSort( a );

        SORT( a );
        checkSort( a );

        quickSelect( a, vec_length / 2 );
        //cout << a[vec_length / 2 - 1].size( ) << " " << vec_length / 2 << endl;
    }

    cout << "Checking SORT, Fig 7.13" << endl;
    int N = vec_length * vec_length;
    vector<int> b( N );
    for( int i = 0; i < N; ++i )
        b[ i ] = i;
    SORT( b );
    for( int i = 0; i < N; ++i )
        if( b[ i ] != i )
            cout << "OOPS!!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of declarations in C++ is very important.  Template functions in particular have to be declared before they're used.  The solution is to move the definition for e.g. `percDown` higher up in the file than its first use.